# How do I reduce the redundancy of this code?

Tags: java

I am not allowed to use more than three print statements. I tried doing by creating private method but it didn't work out.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numBills1 = spending(console, "John");
    int numBills2 = spending(console, "Jane");
    System.out.println("John needs " + numBills1 + " bills");
    System.out.println("Jane needs " + numBills2 + " bills");
}

public static int spending(Scanner console, String name) {
    System.out.print("How much will " + name + " be spending? ");
    double amount = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.println();
    int numBills = (int) (amount / 20.0);
    if (numBills * 20.0 < amount) {
        numBills++;
    }
    return numBills;
}
```

Comment: Use \n new line

Comment: If this code is working, you should be asking for a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please add a description in which way the Code fails to meet your expectations.

Comment: In what way didn’t the private method work out??

Answer (score 1):

You can try to store the output text in an instance variable then use one print statement for all your outputs.

```
private static String output="";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    spending(console, "John");
    spending(console, "Jane");
    System.out.println(output);
}
public static void spending(Scanner console, String name) {
    System.out.print("How much will " + name + " be spending? ");
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(console.nextLine());
    int numBills = (int) (amount / 20.0);
    if (numBills * 20.0 < amount) {
        numBills++;
    }
    output += name + " needs "+numBills+" bills\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using new line `\n`

```
System.out.println("John needs " + numBills1 + " bills\nJane needs " + numBills2 + " bills");
```

You also don't really need the empty print. Remove

```
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have **two solutions**, you can use just **two** if you want you can just concatenate your String using `\n`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //...
    System.out.println("John needs " + numBills1 + " bills" + "\n" + "Jane needs " + numBills2 + " bills");
    //---------------------------------------------------------^^^----------
}
```

and in your method `spending` you can change `print` to `println`:

```
public static int spending(Scanner console, String name) {
    System.out.println("How much will " + name + " be spending? ");
    //--------------^^---------------------------------------------
```

and remove the :

```
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was already mentioned you can concatenate the two strings and make your print on the methode a `System.out.println("Text here");`

Also you don't need to make the scanner a argument on the methode, you could simply, before the main methode, type:

```
static Scanner output = new Scanner (System.in);
```

This way you can use the scanner throughout the (kind of) whole program like this:

```
public static int spending(String name) 
{
        System.out.println("How much will " + name + " be spending? ");
        double amount = output.nextDouble();  

        int numBills = (int) (amount / 20.0);
        if (numBills * 20.0 < amount)
        {
            numBills++;
        }
        return numBills;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("The name : ");
        String name = console.nextLine();
        System.out.print("How much will " + name + " be spending? ");
        double amount = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(name + " needs " + calculateBills(amount) + " bills");
    }
}

private static int calculateBills(double amount) {
    int numBills = (int) (amount / 20.0);
    if (numBills * 20.0 < amount) {
        numBills++;
    }
    return numBills;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to round up. One way to do this is

```
int numBills = (int) Math.ceil(amount / 20);
```